# Getting elapsed time from AlarmManager

Tags: android, android-service

Pretty new to android, so forgive me if this is a dumb question...

So, I'm making an app with a countdown timer that will ring periodically, and then again when the countdown hits zero - simple enough. However, I want the app to keep running even when the user closes the application or the phone is asleep, so that whenever the timer rings, the app will wake up and display an activity showing the time until the countdown is finished. To do this, I'll need to use a service, and lo and behold, the google devs made the AlarmManager service just for me! Sweet!

However, I noticed 2 things:

1) the AlarmManager class has no default constructor, so I'm assuming I can't just extend it and tack some logic on so that I can get all this done in one shot. Ok, cool - I'll just make a service that instantiates AlarmManager at the start, and implement my logic there.

2) In the documentation, I don't see any way of *getting* either the elapsed time or the remaining time from AlarmManager once it is running.

So, my question is: does this mean that I will need two timers that I start at the same time? Say, an AlarmManager to wake the phone up and call the activity, and a CountDownTimer contained in the service to hold the remaining time and call the alarm ringtone?

Thanks for helping out my clueless ass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could extend `AlarmManager`. However the common way is to get an instance of it, which is running as a system service.

Get the instance using `Context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE)` and you will be able to register your `PendingIntent` to that system service, which is independent to your own app. The `PendingIntent` can either start an activity or send broadcast with some `Intent`. You don't monitor the elapsed time constantly in `AlarmManager`. Rather, you calculate the time difference between the current time of your method call, and the desired time to fire your event. And then you set an alarm in `AlarmManager` with a `PendingIntent` representing the action you wish to take at that interval, or a time point.

On the other hand, if you want maximum flexibility, run your service as foreground service and listen for system broadcast like `ACTION_TIME_TICK`, which is fired every minute. Alternatively if you don't run service in foreground you could also run your service with `START_STICKY`, which guarantees that your service will be restarted after the system kills it (due to sleep or closing app). Think this as a background service that is constantly running. This provides you a lot of flexibility in your implementation.